# In the song 'Come together', I want to know the meaning of 'over'

Tags: word-in-context

I like the song "Come Together" by the Beatles. However, I don't know the exact meaning of the word "over" in the lyrics:

> **[*Chorus*]**
>   Come together, right now
>   **Over** me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, Lennon's lyrics can have many interpretations. My own is in keeping with the unifying sentiment of the times. Each verse describes a person who is divisive in some way. The chorus tells us to "come together," to put aside our differences, "over" the person in the verse, that is, *over* his objections.

Comment: But "over me" never means "over my objections" in normal speech. It seems you're making things up. And even if it did have that meaning, it would be nonsensical: come together, despite my objections? Despite my objections to what, your coming together?

Answer (score 2):

With "come together", the object of **over** is the cause, justification, basis, or occasion of an action whose purpose is to attain or express agreement, covenant, unity, solidarity, or camaraderie.

> They discussed the deal over a cup of coffee.
>
> They celebrated their success over a few beers at the pub.
>
> To express our gratitude we come together over a thanksgiving feast.

Consider also the notion of "covenant **over** dead victims" described [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6xGpIJKW-sC&pg=PA146&dq=%22over%20sacrifice%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj927aji9zVAhWS14MKHT7LBMMQ6AEIfjAP#v=onepage&q=%22over%20sacrifice%22&f=false) (pp. 146-47).

And this, about a balloonist setting a world record for the highest skydive:

> "The online global community came together for an hour to witness
>   history and I don't recall anything like it. Everyone was positively
>   giddy. For an hour we *came together over* one breathtaking event."
>   Derman Scott, (*[The New Rules of Marketing & PR](https://books.google.com/books?id=3-Wm036rsvoC&pg=PT179&dq=%22came%20together%20over%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT6ITK_d3VAhXHNSYKHUozDZwQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=%22came%20together%20over%22&f=false)* )

The breathtaking event, as it was watched and shared by the online community, was an occasion for them to unite.

P.S. With "fighting", "disagreeing", etc. the object of **over** is the cause, justification, basis, or occasion of dissent.

> The dogs were fighting over a bone.
>
> The siblings had a falling out over how to divide the estate.
>
> They had a disagreement over States rights versus Federal powers.